# Extinction of a Markov process with strong drift towards (a neighbourhood of) the absorbing state

Tags: pr.probability, markov-chains

Let $(X_t)_{t\in\mathbb{R}\geqslant 0}$ be a Markov Jump Process on a discrete state space $S\cup \{0\}$, with $0$ an absorbing state. If $T_0$ is the hitting time of $0$, I want to prove that

$$ \mathbb{P}_x(T_0<+\infty)=1$$

knowing these facts:

1) For some (finite) neighbourhood of $0$, say $C$, $\mathbb{P}_x(T_C<+\infty)=1\ \ \forall x \notin C$

2) For all $x\in C$, there's a positive probability $p_x$ of eventually reaching $0$,starting from $x$ (This implies there's a uniform probability $p>0$ of reaching $0$ from *any* state in $C$,as $C$ is finite).

The strategy would be to bound $T_0$ from above, by a Geometric (with parameter $q:=1-p$) sum of iid variables $T_C^{(i)}$ plus the times spent inside $C$.

I would like to write this idea properly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions 1) and 2) imply that the chain is Harris-recurrent in
the sense of 
Definition 6.1.1 in [Glynn](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjDmcLrsuTWAhXrz1QKHQuWAnsQFggyMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstanford.edu%2Fclass%2Fmsande321%2FHandouts%2F06%2520Harris%2520Recurrence.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3qJM6gP4KWBM9dKz00Bxlh). 
By Remark 6.1.1 there, 
there exists $z\in S$ such
that $P_x(\tau(z) < \infty$) = 1 for $x\in S$, where $\tau(z) = \inf\{n\ge1 : X_n = z\}$.
From that, your desired conclusion, $P_x(T_0<\infty)=1$, follows immediately. Indeed, $0$ is absorbing and hence $z$ is necessarily $0$, since for any $z\ne0$ one has $P_0(\tau(z)<\infty)=0\ne1$.

However, I do not know how to prove the mentioned remark; perhaps you can ask Peter Glynn about that.

Theorem 14.2.7 in [Athreya and Lahiri](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj3ptfsneTWAhVhlFQKHQBhDRUQFggzMAQ&url=ftp%3A%2F%2Fnozdr.ru%2Fbiblio%2Fkolxo3%2FM%2FMV%2FAthreya%2520K.B.%2C%2520Lahiri%2520S.N.%2520Measure%2520Theory%2520and%2520Probability%2520Theory%2520(Springer%2C%25202006)(ISBN%2520038732903X)(624s)_MV_.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2PHHoGKxae7u4kyrZGxDlQ)
seems of relevance here, but you seem to lack condition (2.15) in that theorem (which may be somehow established, though).

Comment: From what I understand, for conditions 1) and 2) to imply Harris Recurrence, I need to work a little bit, here's what I think I would need to do:

Comment: a) As this chain is in continuous time, take $(Y_n)$ the *jump chain*. Then
b) Condition 1 holds
c) For condition 2) take $\varphi=\delta_0$ and $\lambda=p$. And $m$ (here I'm not sure) would be the maximum of $m_x$, $x\in C$ (where $m_x$ is such that $p_{x0}^{(m_x)}>0$).  

Is this what you thought?

Comment: And a technicality: Is $\tau(z)$  well defined under $\mathbb{P}_z$ , when $z$ is an absorbing state?

Comment: Before your editing the question, I somehow perceived that you deal with a discrete-time process. For $m$ (according to Glynn's presentation), one can indeed take $\max_{x\in C}m_x$, because $p_{x0}^{(m_x)}>0$ implies $p_{x0}^{(n)}>0$ for all $n\ge m_x$, since $0$ is absorbing. Also, I don't see a problem with the definition of $\tau(z)$, as it is defined path-wise, without involving any probability measure.

Answer (score 1):

I see no difference between working with the continuous time process and discrete-time process for this problem. Hence, to mitigate the unnecessary burden of notation, the rest of the work will be presented as the problem is posed for discrete time process.

Denote that:

- $ S'=S\cup \{ 0 \}$
- $C=\{ c_1,c_2,..,c_n\}$
- $ \mathcal{ D}(S'), \mathcal{ D}(C)  $ are family of all positive distributions over $S'$ and $C$ , respectively.
- $m(t,V) = \mathbb{P}_{V}( X^t=0 ) $ for $ t \in \mathbb{N}, V \in \mathcal{D}(C)$
- $m(t) = \inf_{  V \in \mathcal{D}(C) } m(t,V)$
- $P$ is the transition matrix of the chain.

Before the demonstration of the problem, we start with some propositions

Firstly with those concerning $m(t)$

**Proposition 1:** For all $t \in \mathbb{N}$ , $\begin{array}{lccl}  m_t : & \mathcal{D}(C) &  \rightarrow &  \mathbb{R} \\ &V & \mapsto& m(t,V)  \end{array} $ is an affine function.

*Demonstration 1* If each distribution represented as a stochastic row vector, $m(t,V) $ is indeed equal to $ VP^t\delta_0^T$ .QED

**Proposition 2:** For each $t$, the infimum in the definition of $m(t)$ is achievable, ie. $ \exists \mu_t \in \mathcal{D}(C) : m(t) = m(t, \mu_t)$.

*Demonstration 2* Following from the previous proposition, in looking for the infimum of $m(t,V)$ over $\mathcal{D}(C)$, we are minimizing a continuous function over a compact set ( $  dim( \mathcal{D}(C) ) < \infty $ as $ |C| <\infty$ ). It therefore has a minimum.

*Remark 1:* As $m_t$ is affine, it is reasonable to even suppose that $\mu_t = \delta_{d_t} $ for some $ d_t \in C$.

**Proposition 3:** $( m(t) )_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an increasing sequence.

*Demonstration 3* The *proposition 2* and the fact that $0$ is an absorbing state imply :

$m(t+1) = m(t+1, \mu_{t+1}) = \mathbb{P}_{\mu_{t+1}}( X^{t+1} =0)$

$ \ge \mathbb{P}_{\mu_{t+1}}( X^{t} =0) \ge \min_{\mu \in \mathcal{D}(C)} \mathbb{P}_{\mu}( X^{t} =0) =m(t)$ . QED

Then, some proposition for estimation.

**Proposition 4:** $ \exists p> 0 $ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that : $  \mathbb{P}_{U}(X^N =0)>p $ for all $U \in \mathcal{D}(C)$ ,ie :

$ m(N) >p$.

*Demonstration 4* The second condition of the problem shows that for each $ i \in \mathbb{1,n}$ , there is $p_i>0$ and $N_i>0$ such that :

$\mathbb{P}_{c_i}( X^{N_i} =0 ) > p_i$

Choose $ p= \min( p_1,p_2,..,p_n); N=\max(N_1,N_2,..,N_n)$, using the fact that $0$ is an absorbing state, we deduce that:

$\mathbb{P}_{c}( X^{N} =0 ) > p \forall c \in C$

Therefore, QED.

And the last ingredient,

**Proposition 5:** $\lim_{ t \rightarrow \infty} m(t) = \inf_{ \mu \in \mathcal{D}(C) } \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \mathcal{P}_{\mu}(X^t = 0)= I $

*Demonstration 5:*

As $0$ is an absorbing state, for all $ \mu \in \mathcal{D}(C) $, $ ( \mathcal{P}_{\mu}(X^t = 0) )_{t \ge 0 }$ is an increasing state.

Therefore, $ \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \mathcal{P}_{\mu}(X^t = 0) \ge \mathcal{P}_{\mu}(X^n = 0) \ge m(n) \forall n$

$\Rightarrow RHS \ge LHS$

On the other hand, following the *remark 1* , and the fact that $|C| $ is finite, we deduce that :

$\exists$  an strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers $(n_i)_{i \ge 0}$ and a state $c^* \in C$ such that:

$ m(n_i) = m(n_i, \delta_{c^*} ) = \mathbb{P}_{\delta_{c^*} }( X^{n_i} =0)$

As $(m(t))_{t \ge 0}$ is an strictly increasing sequence, we also deduce:
$\Rightarrow \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} m(t)  = \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}_{\delta_{c^*} }( X^{t} =0) \ge \inf_{ \mu \in \mathcal{D}(C) } \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \mathcal{P}_{\mu}(X^t = 0)  $

$\Rightarrow LHS \ge RHS$

QED.

Let's begin the main demonstration

**Demonstration**

For all $t>0$ , $ \mu \in \mathcal{D}_{C}$ and the fact that $0$ is an absoribng state **(*)** , we have:

- $ \mathbb{P}_{\mu} (X^{N+t} =0) >p$ ( $N,p$ are defined as in the *Proposition 3*)
- Take $V \in \mathcal{D}(S' )$ such that $ \mathbb{P}_{\mu} (X^{N} =s |X^N \ne 0 )= \mathbb{P}_{V}( X_0=s)$

  $\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}_{\mu} (X^{N+t} =0 |X^N \ne 0 )= \mathbb{P}_{V}( X^t=0) \forall t $

From those, we deduce:

$ \mathbb{P}_{\mu} (X^{N+t} =0) \ge p+(1-p)  \mathbb{P}_{V} (X^{t} =0)$ (1)

On the other hand, we have:

- $  \mathbb{P}_{V} (X^{t} =0) = \sum_{i\ge 0 }^t \mathbb{P}_{V} (X^{t} =0 | T_{C} =i) \mathbb{P}_{V}( T_{C} =i)= E$

  Choose $\mu_i \in \mathcal{D}(C) $ such that:

  - $ \mathbb{P}_{V} (X^{t} =0 | T_{C} =i) =\mathbb{P}_{ \mu_i }( X^{t-i}=0)$( the same way we chose V )

  Therefore,

  $ E=   \sum_{i\ge 0 }^t \mathbb{P}_{\mu_i } (X^{t-i} =0 ) \mathbb{P}_{V}( T_{C} =i) \ge \sum_{i\ge 0 }^t m(t-i) \mathbb{P}_{V}( T_{C} =i)   $ (2)

From (1) and (2) , we get:

$\mathbb{P}_{\mu} (X^{N+t} =0) \ge p+(1-p)( \sum_{i\ge 0 }^t m(t-i) \mathbb{P}_{V}( T_{C} =i)) $

Take the limit and do some calculations,

$ \lim_{ t \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}_{\mu} (X^{t} =0) \ge  p+(1-p)( I ( \sum_{i\ge 0 }^t \mathbb{P}_{V}( T_{C} =i) )$

$ = p+(1-p)I (\mathbb{P}_{V}( T_C<\infty))$

$ =  p+(1-p)(I \sum_{s \in S'} \mathbb{P}_{s}( T_C<\infty)\mathbb{P}_V ( X_0=s'))$

$ =  p+(1-p)(I \sum_{s \in S'} \mathbb{P}_V ( X_0=s'))$ (first condition)

$ = p+(1-p)I$

Then take the infimum.

$\Rightarrow I \ge p+(1-p)I \Rightarrow I=1$

Therefore, $ \forall \mu \in \mathcal{D}(C) :  \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}_{\mu}(X^t = 0)=1$

Which gives $ \mathbb{P}_{\mu}( T_0 < \infty)=1$.**(**)**

Finally, $\forall x \in S'$, we have:

$ \mathbb{P}_{x}( T_0 < \infty) \ge \sum_{i \ge 0 } \mathbb{P}_{x}( T_0 < \infty | T_C = i) \mathbb{P}_{x}( T_C=i) $

$ =^{**}  \sum_{i \ge 0 } 1. \mathbb{P}_{x}( T_C=i) = \mathbb{P}_{x}( T_C< \infty)=1$ Q.E.D

Comment: How do you get "that $\exists M \in \mathbb{N}: \mathbb{P}_{U} ( X_M \in C ) \ge 1 -\epsilon$"?

Comment: Yeah, it requires some work and I didn't state it clearly.

Comment: Without loss of generality, as $S$ is countable, we can represent $S'=S\cup \{0\} =\{ s_0,s_1,...,s_n,..\} $ . Because $U$ is a distribution over $S'$, $\exists n \in \mathbb{N} $ such that : $ \sum_{i=0}^{n} \mathbb{P}_{U}( X_0= s_i) > 1-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ . On other hand, from the first condition , $ \exists M \in \mathbb{N} : \mathbb{P}_{s_i} ( X_M \in C) > 1-\frac{\epsilon{2} \for i \in \overline{0,n}$ ; from which we get the above proposition.

Comment: And how do you show that "$\exists M \in \mathbb{N} : \mathbb{P}_{s_i} ( X_M \in C) > 1-\frac\epsilon{2} \text{ for } i \in \overline{0,n}$"? This latter version indeed seems very close to the previous one, which was quite unclear to me:  "that $\exists M \in \mathbb{N}: \mathbb{P}_{U} ( X_M \in C ) \ge 1 -\epsilon$". The same $M$ for all $s_i$, and with probability $> 1-\frac\epsilon{2}$? I have no idea how to get this.

Comment: Thank you again for your reply. 

I think you have a remark about the fact that $ |S'|$ could be infinite. In the proof, it just states that $M$ holds for a **finite**  number of $s_i$ ( $s_1,..,s_n$ in this case). As the desired inequality can be implied as following:

$ \mathbb{P}_{U}(X_M \in C ) = \sum_{i \ge 0}  \mathbb{P}_{s_i}(X_M \in C )   \mathbb{P}_{U}(X_0 = s_i) \ge \sum_{i \ge 0}^n   \mathbb{P}_{s_i}(X_M \in C )   \mathbb{P}_{U}(X_0 = s_i) $

$\ge  (1-\frac{\epsilon}{ 2}) \sum_{i \ge 0}^n \mathbb{P}_{U}(X_0 = s_i) >1-\epsilon$

Comment: My comments have nothing to do with $|S'|$ possibly being infinite. The problem is with the penultimate inequality in your latest comment, which apparently is based on the inequality $\mathbb P_{s_i}(X_M\in C)\ge1-\epsilon/2$ for some $M$ and all $i=1,\dots,n$. But how you get this inequality is a complete mystery for me, even if $n=1$. It is given that the chain will be in a state in $C$ at some random time moment -- but how can you claim that that moment will be a definite one (say, $M=100$) with probability close to $1$? I think it should even be easy to construct a counterexample to this.

Comment: Yeah, I did it again, and all wrote down explicitly.

Comment: This proof looks very different from your previous one; for one thing, there is no $1-\epsilon$ or $1-\epsilon/2$ anymore. One thing the meaning of which I cannot get this time is this: "Take $V \in \mathcal{D}(S' )$ such that $ \mathbb{P}_{\mu} (X^{N} =s |X^N \ne 0 )= \mathbb{P}_{V}( X_0=s)$ 
 $\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}_{\mu} (X^{N+t} =0 |X^N \ne 0 )= \mathbb{P}_{V}( X^t=0) \forall t $". What is $s$ here? Why does such a $V$ exists? "[S]uch that" what -- the implication that follows the "such that"?